# Making edges thinner in an image

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm writing a simple U-Net to predict edges of the cells in the image. But I'm having a hard time to make the predicted edges thinner:

[image]

Loss is BCE. The training set is small, only 32 pairs of images (augmentation is used).

I had an idea to put an additional penalty to penalize neighbor pixels but thought maybe there are more elegant ways of doing it. Maybe even in the post processing stage

Comment: Look up “thinning”, a filter from Mathematical Morphology.

Comment: I will take a look at it, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo though I'm curious what is the reason of this underfit on the data. As I said the train subset is pretty small but still I'm not able to fully grasp the reason and tackle it accordingly.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Also I lied about using "simple" `U-net`. I was actually using `TernausNet` with pre-trained encoder weights on Imagenet.